On the description of the Fano variety given by a non degenerate quadric surface
Given $X=V(G)\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ where $G(Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,Z_3)=Z_0Z_3-Z_1Z_2$, I would like to describe $F_1(X)\subset\mathbb{G}(1,3)\subset\mathbb{P}^5$ (where given $W\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ closed, we define $F_k(W)=\{\Lambda\in\mathbb{G}(k,n)\text{|}\,\Lambda\subset W\}$). Now from exercise 6.20 in Harris' book Algebraic Geometry, I know that $F_1(X)$ is a union of two conic curves, but I can't find the equations. 
Here's my attempt:
We restrict our attention to the affine open subset $U\subset G(2, 4)$ of $2$-planes $\Lambda\subset \mathbb{K}^4$ complementary to a given $2$-plane $\Lambda_0$ and exhibit explicitly equations for $F_k(X)\cap U\subset\mathbb{K}^4$. Choosing a basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4)$ of $\mathbb{K}^4$ let $(e_3,e_4)$ be a basis for $\Lambda_0$ then every plane in affine open set is given by the row of the matrix:\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & x_{1,1}& x_{1,2}\\
0 & 1 & x_{2,1}& x_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}
Then the subspace spanned by the row of the matrix is contained in $X$ if and only if \begin{align}G(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_1x_{1,1}+\lambda_2x_{2,1},\lambda_1x_{1,2}+\lambda_2x_{2,2})=0\end{align}
for all $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)\in\mathbb{K}^2$. So we have\begin{align}\lambda_1^2x_{1,2}+\lambda_1\lambda_2(x_{2,2}-x_{1,1})-\lambda_2^2x_{2,1}=0.\end{align}
But now I don't know how to conclude and finding the equation in the plücker coordinates.
Any help?

You obtained a quadratic polynomial in $\lambda$ with coefficients depending on $x$, and you want this polynomial to be identically zero. This gives equations
$$
x_{1,2} = x_{2,2} - x_{1,1} = x_{2,1} = 0.
$$
So, in this chart you obtain the line. If you look at the image of this line under the Plucker embedding, you will see the curve
$$
(e_1 + te_3) \wedge (e_2 + te_4) = 
e_1 \wedge e_2 + t(e_1 \wedge e_4 - e_2 \wedge e_3) + t^2 e_3 \wedge e_4,
$$
which is a conic with equations
$$
p_{1,3} = p_{2,4} = p_{1,4} + p_{2,3} = p_{1,2}p_{3,4} - p_{1,4}^2 = 0,
$$
where $p_{i,j}$ are the Plucker coordinates.
The other conic can be found in a different chart.

I forgot that the polynomial must be \textbf{identically} zero! So the only solutions for all $\lambda$'s are the ones you gave me. For the other conic I should change for example the base of $\Lambda_0$, right?

Yes, the other conic is in another chart.
